# How can I determine what's under my siding and cover it.

Tags: exterior, siding

TL;DR: want to install a pergola structure over my window, need to remove one row of siding. not sure how to proceed.

My house has a concrete foundation, then bricks up to what looks like the second level, then Aluminum siding. I want to install a pergola structure over my bay window. The brick runs up both sides of the window. The siding covers the top of the window. It is not clear to me if the brick runs across the top of the window frame or not.

So, my question: what is most likely under that siding? OSB? If I remove the row of siding and there is OSB underneath what I could I do to cover it properly? Add more Brick? Brick facade? I wouldn't want to put siding between the house and the pergola. And obviously, if it's just more brick then I'd do nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The age of the house may help. A newer home usually has osb or CDX plywood sheeting older homes may just have brick.

Comment: A picture of the wall in question would really be good. If the house is in a community where houses where built by perhaps a single builder will help a little. And definatly, definately the age of the house is imperative in giving an educated guess. Certain type of materials were used over the years. For example, if your siding is aluminum, I would guess the house was built in the 70's. If it is painted steel, it may be built in the 60's, or it could have been resided, and it is a much older house.

Comment: its from the 70s, built in the greater toronto area.